# Why is SvcTraceViewer included into Windows SDK and NOT to .NET Framework tools?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, sdk

It is a WCF tool and why it is located within Windows SDK and not inside the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Windows SDK is now the "Windows SDK for Windows [n] and .NET Framework [m]" - so ultimately Microsoft are saying that this **is** an SDK tool... the choice of whether to go into the SDK or tools... well, it could go either way really...